# which parts of the bitcoin core codebase need to be removed to create an altcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin

As I was going through the bitcoin core code with a mind towards creating a brand spankin' new altcoin, I came across some parts that are (*seemingly*) obviously irrelevant/unnecessary/hinderance-ish:

```
// The best chain should have at least this much work.
consensus.nMinimumChainWork = uint256S("0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f057509eba81aed91");
```

Additionally the code after this sentence should likely be eliminated as well.

```
// By default assume that the signatures in ancestors of this block are valid.
consensus.defaultAssumeValid = uint256S("0x00000000000128796ee387cf110ccb9d2f36cffaf7f73079c995377c65ac0dcc"); //1079274
```

and so I began to wonder...

what else needs to be purged from that codebase to give birth to a new fork coin?

Comment: Could whoever voted to reopen explain why they did so? I feel that this question here is either a duplicate of the other or not specific enough to clearly distinguish itself from the duplicate. Also, the two specific examples would make good separate questions.